# How can I generate 15 different numbers and assign the numbers to a variable

Tags: python-3.x

Basically I am trying to make a game, where I generate 15 different numbers between 1 and 15, and then assign them all to one variable for each number.

I tried using random.sample but it wasn't able to assign the numbers to a single variable per number. Alternatively, I tried typing out 'if' statements, determining if there is duplicates, but it didn't work, and takes a long time.

```py
numbers = random.sample(range(15), 15)
print(numbers)
```

I hoped that I could somehow assign each number to a variable, for example, the first number it generates will be called firstnumber, secondnumber will be the second number generated.

Comment: Why you can't assign those 15 values to one list instead of creating 15 variables. It's also saving your memory.

Comment: This is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/4518341), but why do you need this? A list seems to be the right datatype.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a list and append to it:

```
vars = []
for _ in range(x):
    vars.append(random.choice(y))
```

But if you really want your method, you can use a dictionary:

```
vars = {}
for i in range(x):
    vars[f'var{i+1}'] = random.choice(y)
```